# How to unit test an AWS SDK method called in a separate method?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, aws-sdk, sinon

I am currently writing a piece of code which simply uploads a file to an S3 bucket. This is a serverless NodeJS project written in Typescript. For testing, I am using Mocha, Chai, and attempting to use SinonJS.

I have a class with a method which uploads a buffer as a file to S3:

```
import { S3 } from "aws-sdk"
import { S3UploadError } from "../errors/S3UploadError"

/**
 * This class provides a means of interacting with S3
 *
 * @export
 * @class AWSS3Manager
 */
export class AWSS3Manager {
    /**
     * Instance of S3
     *
     * @private
     * @type {S3}
     * @memberof AWSS3Manager
     */
    private s3: S3

    /**
     * Creates an instance of AWSS3Manager.
     *
     * @memberof AWSS3Manager
     */
    public constructor() {
        this.s3 = new S3()
    }

    /**
     * Upload a file to bucket on S3 by using a buffer
     *
     * @param {Buffer} body
     * @param {string} bucketName
     * @param {string} fileName
     * @returns {Promise<PromiseResult<S3.PutObjectOutput, S3UploadError>>}
     * @memberof AWSS3Manager
     */
    public async upload(body: Buffer, bucketName: string, fileName: string) {
        const params = {
            Body: body,
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
        }

        try {
            return await this.s3.putObject(params).promise()
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            throw new S3UploadError()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is the right thing to be doing, but I want to test the `upload` method of the above class. And in my mind, to do that I need to mock the response from `S3.putObject` in order to ensure that the external library doesn't cause interference. However, no matter what I have tried I can't get it to work.

I have tried stubbing the `S3` put object method, but to no avail:

```
chai.should()
const assert = chai.assert
const expect = chai.expect
const s3manager = new AWSS3Manager()
let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox
let spy

describe("AWSS3Manager behaves as expected", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
        spy = sinon.spy()

    })
    afterEach(() => {
        // Restore the default sandbox here
        sandbox.restore()
    })

    it("Uploads a file correctly to S3", async () => {
        const putObjectStub = sinon.stub(S3.prototype, "putObject")
        putObjectStub.yields("ERROR", 'data')
        //const uploadStub = sandbox.stub(s3manager, "upload").resolves("Yup")
        //sandbox.stub(AWS, "S3").resolves('HEYY')
        const test = await s3manager.upload(new Buffer("ddds"), "TestBucket", "Test")
        assert(putObjectStub.called)
    })
})
```

I have tried stubbing the S3 method, and also stubbing the upload method its self and seeing how many calls there was to putObject but I can't get nothing to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Wouldn't constructor injection of the s3 instance make testing allot easier?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation attempting to stub out the `putObject` call on an `S3` instance that I was then returning chained with `.promise()`. See below:

```
export class UploadService {
  s3: S3

  constructor() {
    this.s3 = new S3({ region: 'us-west-2' })
  }

  upload({ data, path }: { data: string, path: string }) {
    const uploadParams = {
      Body: data,
      Bucket: bucketName, // defined elsewhere
      Key: path
    }
    return this.s3.putObject(uploadParams).promise()
  }
}
```

I dug into the `aws-sdk` definitions and came up with this test setup--I don't love it because it's kinda exposing the guts of the sdk that you shouldn't have to think about but it passes the typescript compiler and gets the job done ‍♂️

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import * as sinon from 'sinon'
import { UploadService } from '../../src/services/upload_service'
import { Request, Service } from 'aws-sdk'

describe('UploadService', () => {
  const uploadService = new UploadService()
  let uploadStub: sinon.SinonStub

  describe('#upload', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      uploadStub = sinon
        .stub(uploadService.s3, 'putObject')
        .returns(new Request(new Service(), 'put'))
    })
    it('uploads the data to the specified path in S3', async () => {
      const data = '{"cool": "data"}'
      const path = 'my/cool/file/path'

      await uploadService.upload({ data, path })

      expect(uploadStub).to.have.been.calledOnceWith({ data, path })
    })
  })
})
```

Hope that helps!